# How to clear a file via adb?

Tags: android, linux, adb

Similarly to how I view file, using adb functionality:

```
adb shell cat /path/to/file
```

I would like to clear a file, without having to enter adb shell, like so:

```
adb shell clear /path/to/file
```

Second example is a pseudo-code ofc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should clear the file, removing every text in the file:

```
adb shell "> /path/to/file"
```

Comment: Yeah, the first one I am not interested in as it removes my file.
The second one looks like something that would be perfect.
But
bash: /data/data/com.app.my.service/args.txt: No such file or directory
It seems that bash tries to evaluate the ">" sign, instead of adb.

Comment: @ziemowit141 I found another method, see the edited post.